# Clipboard doesn't work between Win7 (local) and Linux (remote)

Tags: debian, windows, clipboard, remote-desktop

I'm using Win7 64-bit and connecting remotely to Debian. The thing is copy/paste doesn't work even for plain text. I've tried killing this process `rdpclip.exe` and create again, but that didn't help.

What should I do?

Comment: You need to give us more information. When you ask questions, always give enough information so that readers can reproduce your problem on their machine. How are you connecting to Debian remotely? I guess xrdp from [what you wrote on your other question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250657/restart-clipboard-for-linux-remote-desktop#comment431982_250657)? (That's not the simplest way to run Linux programs and have them display from Windows — the normal way would be to run an X server on Windows.) What client are you using on the Windows machine?

Comment: How are you attempting to copy-paste exactly? Between what applications? Does it fail from Linux to Linux AND from Windows to Linux AND from Linux to Windows?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 64-bit and connecting through the normal *Windows Remote Desktop*, `mstsc.exe`

And it fails from Win to Linux or Linux to Win

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions I found so far. I think the most stable and good is using **`NoMachine`** (built on `NX protocol`). You need to install one on the client which is a Windows in my case. You can get from [here](http://download.nomachine.com/download/5.0/Windows/nomachine_5.0.53_7.exe). And one on the server, which is Linux Debian in my case. You can get from [here](http://download.nomachine.com/download/5.0/Linux/nomachine_5.0.53_1_amd64.deb).